# Combining COUNTIF and VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vlookup, countif

This is what I'm trying to do. There are two columns. The first one contains the drawing number of a P&ID and The other one contains the IO type. Columns B and N respectively. I want the number of DOs for the drawing number ZCPL-P2179-B1-101. I know a simple COUNTIF function works but it is inefficient since rows keep expanding and it is quite tedious to constantly reselect the ranges.

[image: For example,]

Comment: Are you specifically looking for just the one count? I would probably use a pivot table for this.

Comment: Theres 5 types of IOs and 12 different drawings. So I need to know the number of each type of IOs in each drawing.

Comment: Why not just use countifs? No need to change/reselect ranges, or am I overlooking something here? =COUNTIFS(B:B;"ZCPL-P21729-B1-101";C:C;"DO")

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use Simple Countif with whole column as a Range

**=COUNTIFS(B:B;"B1";C:C;"C1")**

Just drag this formula in the whole column, even if your data is increasing you just have to click once to drag the formula.

Later take out Unique of P&ID number and Dos to find the distinct count.

I hope this helps

Comment: if your data (as stated above) is setup as a table, then as rows are added, the formula will automatically be added... you won't have to continually copy the formula.